# Ploneinfo (as in phpinfo)

Tags: plone

What is the most sraightforward (but not very hackish - unPlonish) way to create a "page" in Plone (v 4.x), which would show some Plone internals info? I'd like to generate a page document, which would paste `dir()` (or whatever my own function) result to `<pre/>` or something like that. Straightforward.. i mean, without having to create a Plone product or having to modify server files directly - just using ZMI..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to install plone.app.debugtoolbar

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.debugtoolbar/

which gives you access to the most imporant informations about the current context object, request data etc.

Comment: this is the best answer for the question title.

Answer (score 3):

Products.DocFinderTab adds a "Doc" tab in the ZMI that allows you to explore the current object and its methods. If you installed with the Unified Installer and use the "develop" configuration, it's already loaded.

Products.Clouseau may still work with recent Plone's, though it's aging. It gives you an AJAX interface to explore the context from within Plone.

Finally, to explore the request object, you may just add:

```
<div tal:replace="structure request" />
```

to a template. That will allow you to check all the HTTP and form variables as well as what's stored in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the ZMI, add a "Script (Python)", and define your function dir() and print the result like this :

```
print dir()
return printed
```

Comment: helpful, but.. i meant the output to be rendered as a document.. and why i get NameError in dir() or globals() ?

Comment: because dir() is undefined in the context. If you want to execute untrusted code, you'll have to create an external method.

Comment: Python Script is not really python; it's python with several teeth removed. `dir()` is one of those.